# Cannot plot hichcharts fro R script in source mode R-Studio

Tags: r, highcharts

I'm trying to plot some (interactive) highcharts plots for some quantmod works. Plots (in R-studio viewer tab) works fine when I "run" them. or polts then interactively on the console window, but shows nothing when I source the whole program.
How can I source the whole script and get all the plots in the viewer window?
How can I save the plots (from the script) to a pdf file?
thanks.

code example:

```
library(quantmod)
library(highcharter)

SPY <- getSymbols("SPY", from = Sys.Date() - lubridate::years(3), auto.assign = FALSE)
SPY <- adjustOHLC(SPY)

SPY.EMA.20 <- EMA(Cl(SPY), n = 20)
SPY.EMA.50 <- EMA(Cl(SPY), n = 50)
SPY.RSI.14 <- RSI(Cl(SPY))
SPY.RSI.SellLevel <- xts(rep(70, NROW(SPY)), index(SPY))
SPY.RSI.BuyLevel <- xts(rep(30, NROW(SPY)), index(SPY))

AAPL <- getSymbols("AAPL", from = Sys.Date() - lubridate::years(3), auto.assign = FALSE)

highchart(type = "stock") %>%
  hc_add_series(AAPL,  name = "AAPL", color = hex_to_rgba("red", 0.7)) 


hchart(AAPL)

highchart(type = "stock") %>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    create_yaxis(3, height = c(3, 1, 1), turnopposite = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(SPY,         yAxis = 0, name = "SPY", color = hex_to_rgba("red", 0.7)) %>%
  hc_add_series(SPY.EMA.20,  yAxis = 0, name = "EMA 20") %>%
  hc_add_series(SPY.EMA.50, yAxis = 0, name = "EMA 50") %>%
  hc_add_series(SPY$SPY.Volume,    yAxis = 1, color = "gray", name = "Volume", type = "column", title = 'volume') %>%
  hc_subtitle(yAxis = 1, text = "Volume", align = "left", style = list(color = "#2b908f", fontWeight = "bold")) %>%
  hc_add_series(SPY.RSI.14,        yAxis = 2, name = "Osciallator", color = hex_to_rgba("green", 0.7)) %>%
  hc_add_series(SPY.RSI.SellLevel, yAxis = 2, color = hex_to_rgba("red", 0.7),  name = "Sell level") %>%
  hc_add_series(SPY.RSI.BuyLevel,  yAxis = 2, color = hex_to_rgba("blue", 0.7), name = "Buy level")
```

Comment: Maybe try wrapping `highchart` in `print`?

Comment: Many thanks. print solved the problem. I guess that's the price of being a newcomer to R.

Comment: Not entirely intuitive, as base `plot` will show up in a sourced script, but `ggplot` will not without a `print` command. Did you get the saving part figured out as well?

Comment: Not Yet. Appreciate any help on that. Spent all day trying to figure out other highchart secrets (like candle colors, preventing highcharts from aggregating candles into longer time-frames, fixed lines instead of the RSI.BuyLevel & RSI.SellLevel kludge, etc.). solved most of it.not yet solved some label issues on the vertical yAxises, but decided to live with it for now. Thanks.

Comment: @avys what issue with labels do you have? Maybe I could help you with it.